# White UI Automation framework: back colour

Tags: testing, user-interface, automation, white-framework

I am using White UI automation for testing in my project. I am stuck at a point where I need to get the background color of a control. Any sample code please ?

Answer (score 2):

This probably is not possible using White unfortunately.  However Windows does provide some methods you can call which might help you out.  If you are using a spy tool and the control you are looking at has TextPattern available, you can get the background color of the control.

Specifically you can try to get a pattern like this (where myElement is of type AutomationElement):

`var textPattern = myElement.GetCurrentPattern(TextPattern.Pattern) as TextPattern;`

If you are able to get an instance of type TextPattern, you can do the following:

`var bgColor = textPattern.DocumentRange.GetAttributeValue(TextPattern.BackgroundColorAttribute)`

This will return a plain old object which you will then need to unbox.  If there are multiple background colors, it will be equal to `TextPattern.MixedAttributeValue`.  Otherwise it will be a number of type `int` which corresponds to an RGB color, so a cast should do the trick to get you the value you need:

`var color = (int) bgColor;`

Of course if the ControlType of the control you are interested in is not Text then you're out of luck unfortunately.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I am trying this approach to see if this works with FlaUI

Comment: I used FlaUI for this, I could see that my control supports TextPattern

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a test app, you could create a textbox and bind the text of the textbox to the control's background. Then you could easily test the text box's text.

Answer (score 0):

I guess White UI automation doesn't have such property, but you are able get  rectangle of a control and recognize color by using .Net libraries.

---

For instance, for recognition red frame in the textbox when you typed incorrect value, process will be following:

1. Get rectangle of a control  by using UI Automation.
2. Make screenshot of this rectangle by using .Net libraries.
3. Go through all pixels by using .Net libraries and verify that in this rectangle we have, for example, more than 30 red pixels.

---

I know that it's brute solution, but it's better than nothing.